# checkbox returning "true,false" from formcollection instead of selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

im having multiple checkboxes  in my aspx page using HtmlHelper.CheckBox

and when the form is submitted using ajax as below in js file 
`var input = $(':input');`

```
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/Home/Post",
    data: input,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function () {

    },
    });
```

and in the controller action method as shown below..

```
 public ActionResult Post(FormCollection Form)
 {

 }
```

and in the Form im not getting the updated values for checkboxes ie all the checkbox values were
returned as "true,false".
if any of the checkbox is not checked or unchecked...Form is not returning as false it still returns as "true,false" instead of false.

even i tried as

```
Form.Get("checkbox0").ConvertTo(typeof(Boolean))

Request.Form["checkbox0"]
```

the aboce code returns "true,false" but the checkbox0 is unchecked so it should return false which is not happening....???

But when i tried using `Html.BeginForm("Post","Home",FormMethod.Post,new {id="x"})` in aspx file
and removed ajax call in the js file... 
then the formcollection in the controller start giving me the expected values for checkboxes...
**but as this approach flickers page after page submit...i need to use ajax approach only**..

**Please let me know how can i retrieve the updated value of the checkbox from the formcollection when using ajax**.

Answer (score 12):

You could always try this:

```
bool checkedValue = Form["checkbox0"].Contains("true");
```

Comment: I noticed this too and have seen this happen in the past with older versions of IE (or was it if I use javascript?)  In any case, I modified Trent's answer in case someone doesn't know how to account for both scenarios :) : - bool checkedValue = (fc["checkbox0"] != null && (fc["checkbox0"].Contains("true") || fc["checkbox0"].Contains("on")) ? true : false);

Comment: This answer works because when the checkbox is checked you get ["true","false"] and when it is not checked you just get ["false"].

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/Post',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function () {

    },
});
```

And also I would recommend you using a view model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

where for example you have a list of values:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ItemViewModel[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

and for which you generated a list of checkboxes in your strongly typed view:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < Model.Items.Length; i++) { %>
    <%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Items[i].Id) %>
    <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Items[i].IsSelected) %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: i have other controls like Html textbox,Dropdown...also....please let me know how can i handle the same

Comment: @user1065358, you simply add corresponding properties to your view model.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string abc =  ((string[])(collection.GetValue("checkbox0").RawValue))[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same problem and then came across the below link
http://www.mindstorminteractive.com/topics/jquery-fix-asp-net-mvc-checkbox-truefalse-value/

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").each(function () {
        fixHiddenCheckField(this);
    });

    $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
        fixHiddenCheckField(this);
    });
});

function fixHiddenCheckField(checkField) {
    var name = $(checkField).attr("name");
    var hiddenSelector = "input:hidden[name=" + name + "]";
    var checkBoxesInListSelector = "input:checkbox[name=" + name + "]";
    var checkedCheckBoxesInListSelector = "input:checked[name=" + name + "]";

    if ($(checkedCheckBoxesInListSelector).length >= 1 || $(checkBoxesInListSelector).length > 1) {
        $("input").remove(hiddenSelector);
    }
    else {
        if ($(hiddenSelector).length == 0)
            $(checkField).parents("form").append("<input type='hidden' name='"+name+"' value='false' />");
    }
}
```

In the blog it is explained that the above code removes the hidden field when checking the box, then adding a duplicate one back to the parent form when unchecked.To handle lists,checking the total length of checkboxes with this name. If there is more than one, it is assumed this is a list, so we remove the hidden fields. If we need an unchecked list to produce a single value of false, simply don’t check for $(checkBoxesInListSelector).length > 1 in the if statement.